# ORA-12545: Network Transport: Unable to resolve connect hostname, using VS 2019 in Debug (IIS Express)

Tags: oracle, .net-4.6.2

I am having an issue connecting to a Oracle Database, using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess v21.12., Visual Studio 2019.  I am using .Net Framework 4.6.2.

I am getting a "ORA-12545: Network Transport: Unable to resolve connect hostname" error when trying to connect.  This only finding this while in the web (IIS Express) debug environment of VS 2019.  I write a separate DLL for the oracle connections, and tested it using NUnit.  The connection works fine, but when I add the same dll to the web project the connection failure is thrown.

I am using a connection string

Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=)));User Id=;Password=

Using the Host name, and IP Address.
Building a separate Dll and testing outside the IIS Express environment (successful)
Using mulitple version of Oracle.ManagedAccess

Expected result is a Connection to the DB server

Comment: Sounds like when you use the DLL in your web project that the required Oracle client files are not in your path but they are when you test the DLL separately.